# Spark Dataframe writing to google pubsub

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to write the Parquet files to Pubsub through Spark on a Dataproc cluster.

I have used below pseudo code

```
dataFrame
      .as[MyCaseClass]
      .foreachPartition(partition => {
          val topicName = "projects/myproject/topics/mytopic"
          val publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build()
          partition.foreach(users => {
            try {
              val jsonUser = users.asJson.noSpaces //using circe scala lib
              val data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(jsonUser)
              val pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).build()
              val message = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage)
            }
            catch {
              case e: Exception => System.out.println("Exception in processing the event " + e.printStackTrace())
            }
          })
          publisher.shutdown()
        }
        catch {
          case e: Exception => System.out.println("Exception in processing the partition = " + e.printStackTrace())
        }
      }
      )
```

Whenever I am submitting this on the cluster I am getting the spark prelaunch errors with exit code 134.

I have shaded the guava and protobuf in my pom. If I run this example through a local test case, it works but if submitted on dataproc I get the errors.
I did not find any relative information about writing the data frame to pub-sub.
Any pointers?

Update:
System Details: Single Node Cluster with N1-Standard-32 (32 Cores,120GB Memory)
Executor Cores: Dynamic enabled

Attaching the stack trace:

```
20/12/22 17:51:43 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Requesting driver to remove executor 1 for reason Container from a bad node: container_1608332157194_0026_01_000002 on host: dataproc-cluster.internal. Exit status: 134. Diagnostics: [2020-12-22 17:51:43.556]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1608332157194_0026_01_000002
Exit code: 134

[2020-12-22 17:51:43.557]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 134. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
/bin/bash: line 1: 19017 Aborted                 /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/bin/java -server -Xmx5586m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1608332157194_0026/container_1608332157194_0026_01_000002/tmp '-Dspark.driver.port=43691' '-Dspark.rpc.message.maxSize=512' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs/application_1608332157194_0026/container_1608332157194_0026_01_000002 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@dataproc-cluster.internal:43691 --executor-id 1 --hostname dataproc-cluster.internal --cores 2 --app-id application_1608332157194_0026 --user-class-path file:/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1608332157194_0026/container_1608332157194_0026_01_000002/__app__.jar --user-class-path file:/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1608332157194_0026/container_1608332157194_0026_01_000002/mySparkJar-1.0.0-0-SNAPSHOT.jar --user-class-path file:/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1608332157194_0026/container_1608332157194_0026_01_000002/org.apache.spark_spark-avro_2.11-2.4.2.jar --user-class-path file:/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1608332157194_0026/container_1608332157194_0026_01_000002/org.spark-project.spark_unused-1.0.0.jar > /var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs/application_1608332157194_0026/container_1608332157194_0026_01_000002/stdout 2> /var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs/application_1608332157194_0026/container_1608332157194_0026_01_000002/stderr
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/spark/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
20/12/22 17:51:36 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: RecordReader initialized will read a total of 11320100 records.
20/12/22 17:51:36 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: at row 0. reading next block
20/12/22 17:51:38 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
20/12/22 17:51:38 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 2301 ms. row count = 11320100
20/12/22 17:51:39 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: RecordReader initialized will read a total of 11320100 records.
20/12/22 17:51:39 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: at row 0. reading next block
20/12/22 17:51:40 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 1411 ms. row count = 11320100
```

Comment: May you attach stacktrace for one of the failures?

Comment: could you also share how you launch your job and parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If job failed early it could be the case that there not enough memory for Spark Driver to start: https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/container-exited-with-a-non-zero-exit-code-134/133

To solve this issue you need to provision Dataproc cluster with master node that has more RAM or allocate more memory/heap for Spark driver and/or Spark executors.

Comment: I have added the stack trace on original thread. Since this was a single node cluster with 120GB ram, I am not able to see how adding more RAM can fix this issue.
As we see there is an OOM, it seems that Spark tries to read the entire directory in memory before writing to pubsub

Comment: Log shows that YARN container for Spark executor starts with `-Xmx5586m` heap - probably you need to allocate more RAM/heap for Spark executors to fix this issue.